# SwiftUI - Issue when trying to hide navigationbar

Tags: swiftui, show-hide, navigationbar

I'm encountering difficulties in hiding the navigation bar in SwiftUI. Despite using .navigationBarHidden(true), the navigation bar remains visible.
Here is my code:

```
struct LogInPage: View {
    // some state variables

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                // some code including a HStack

                VStack(spacing: 35) {
                    // some code

                    Toggle("", isOn: $showPassword)
                        .offset(x: -185)

                    Button(action: {
                        print("Log in button was pressed")
                    }) {
                        Text("Logga in")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.24, blue: 0.73)))
                    }
                    .offset(y: 20)

                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        // some code
                    }
                    .offset(y: 30)

                    Button(action: {
                        print("Register button was pressed")
                        isNavigating = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Skapa konto")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.24, blue: 0.73)))
                    }
                    .offset(y: 60)

                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: RegisterPage(),
                        isActive: $isNavigating,
                        label: {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true) // trying to hide my navigation bar here
      
               
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to solve this problem:

1. By trying this `.navigationBarHidden(true)`, nothing changed
2. By trying this  `.navigationBarHidden(true)`, nothing changed
   .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`
3. By trying this `.navigationBarHidden(true) .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)` , this actually helped me hide my navigation bar text but the arrow still remains.
4. I have also tried to set `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in many parts of my code but still this didn't change anything.
5. I've also checked other people's solution in stackoverflow, who had this problem, but nothing worked.

I think my problem is related to child views and how I have structured my code. I'm not a pro and I am sure my code structure is not so professional. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you don’t have multiple NavigationView somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you wrap the contents inside `NavigationView` and also want to hide the navigation view? Just remove the outer `NavigationView`. It should work.

```swift
var body: some View {
    //NavigationView { <- remove
        ZStack {
            ...
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    //}
}
```

If your contents were wrapped inside a `NavigationView`, the view will create another navigation view. You can check it out by `.navigationBarHidden(false)`.

Suppose that the outside view of your `LogInPage` already embedded in `NavigationView/Stack`. The first attached image is with `NavigationView`. You can see 2 navigation bar views (above and below), separately. The second one is without `NavigationView`. It had a single navigation bar.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining and coming up with images as examples. However, I have a few questions. Is it not necessary to have a navigationView around my content if I want to navigate somewhere with a button? Because earlier, when I didn't have a navigationView, only a link, then I couldn't navigate and I still can't navigate without a NavigationView. Also, the reason why I use emptyView() is because my navigation link does not render any ui content. @son

Comment: You have to control the view hierarchy yourself. I feel like there is a conflict here. Why did you make a view without a navigation view but you still want to navigate somewhere? If you want a view with different states like `case withNav` and `case withoutNav`. You probably split them into 2 views, the same content. I mean navigationView should be a kind of singleton, only 1, unless you present/dismiss another flow. It's a stack of views, which add and remove continuously.

Comment: Absolutely, `NavigationLink` won't work without `NavigationView`. I think you're confusing about where to put `NavigationView` not how to hide it. i.e. If `LogInPage` is a root view and needs to navigate to somewhere, then make a new view nested in `NavigationView`. If `LogInPage` is pushed from somewhere else, then make a new view without nested in `NavigationView` and add `.navigationBarHidden(true)`.

Comment: Thank you so much I think I know now how to deal with my problem. These answers were really helpful, now I understand the problem.

Comment: Do you mind if you mark the answer as accepted? It would be great. @AranAli